# Why is grails application consuming 30% of CPU when deployed on Tomcat?

Tags: performance, tomcat, grails

When i am  deploying my grails application (which is relatively small and simple) on Tomcat server, the performance drops and 30% of CPU is consumed by tomcat

Does anyone have a clue what it might be?

Answer (score 2):

Check the memory settings of the Java VM which runs your Tomcat instance hosting your Grails app.

It may be that continuous garbage collection is going on since you have provided too small memory and Grails has a minimum requirement for its ongoing operations.

Try raise XmX and permgen higher to reduce the need for frequent garbage collection.

Answer (score 0):

The Grails framework itself (and all the frameworks "under the hood" like Spring and Hibernate) consumes a reasonable amount of resources, so even if your app is very lightweight, this shouldn't come as a big surprise.

If your app is very simple, and resources are constrained, Grails is possibly not the best choice.